# Looking for a novel about telepathy and transcendence

Tags: story-identification, novel

I am looking for a telepathy science fiction book probably published in the 1970s or 1980s. I read the last part.

It was titled with the word trans and masters and universe I think.  I can't remember. Two friends of the hero were not corporeal but the hero was in a human body.

It is possible that it was pulp fiction in a novel form. I mean a magazine serial story later published as a book.

It was a paperback and the cover had yellow prominent on a blue background. There was a human face with the skull cap removed and universe showing in the skull.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Can you recall anything else about this book?  Where you read it, was it paperback or hard cover, what colour was the cover...?

Comment: paperback. yellow was prominent on a blue background. a human face with skull cap removed and universe showing in the skull.

Comment: You "read the last part" -- are you sure this was a novel? Maybe a themed anthology?